# LinqToXML XElement to XmlNode

Tags: c#, sharepoint, linq-to-xml

HI,

Is there any 'correct' way to convert an XElement to an XmlNode in C# - LinqToXML makes it nice to build the required XML programmatically but SharePoint web services requires an XmlNode, so whats the best way to mix and match?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use CreateReader() and an XmlDocument like

```
XmlDocument myXmlNode = new XmlDocument();
using (XmlReader reader = myXElement.CreateReader())
{
    myXmlNode.Load(reader);
}
```

XmlDocument derives from XmlNode.

Comment: In case this helps anyone else: An XmlNode's 'Attributes' property is always null unless the node is of type XmlNodeType.Element. So if you are trying to convert an XElement with attributes to an XmlNode, your XmlDocument (myXmlNode) from above will have a null 'Attributes' property. You can obtain the attributes, however, if you use myXmlNode.DocumentElement.Attributes instead.